# How to read grep command result in linux?

Tags: linux, cron, redhat

I want to monitor jboss server status in linux for keep up & running the application.My requirement is  if server down , i need to get the email from server.

So i'm planning to run crontab in linux for every hour or half an hour to check the server status.

```
30 * * * * ps -ef|grep java | mail test@domain.com
```

I' will get grep command result when running above command. So How to read the grep command result to find server is up & running ?

Please advise if anybody have alternative.

Comment: You don't need to `| mail `… Cron will do that for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "result"? The status?

Comment: result means Will get the process id with server name like "test-qa  31723 31658  0 Sep04 ?        00:40:50 /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=300m

Comment: That's what you are mailing. What's your question then?

Comment: Actually, the part "if server is down…get email" looks like more reasonable specification, but that does not match "result of grep" as you just described it.

Comment: I want to read "test-qa" server name. if test-qa then not sending email or sending email as "server down like ...". My question is how to read server name when running command grep.

Comment: If you have any other alternative , Please advise for if server down sending email to support team.

Answer (score 1):

In your crontab file write this:

```
MAILTO="test@domain.com"

30 * * * * pgrep -lf java
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of cron add

```
MAILTO="test@domain.com"
```

This would send the output of commands in cron. You dont require to pipe the output to `mail` again. ([reference](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html))